# My code only works one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code will only work one time.

**Here is my HTML:**

```
 <span id="0" class="add-title">add title</span>
```

**My JavaScript:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

var iTitlesArray = [];  

$(document).on("click", ".add-title", function () { 

    alert(iTitlesArray);

    var thumbId = $(this).attr("id"), 
        thumbIdInt = parseInt(thumbId);             

    var lb_form = $('<div></div>').addClass('lb_form');
    var title_input = $('<input type="text">').addClass('txt-title');
    var btn = $('<div>Ok</div>').addClass('div-btn');   

    lb_form.append(title_input, btn);                   
    $('body').append(lb_form);

    $( ".div-btn" ).on( "click", function() {
            iTitlesArray[thumbIdInt] = $(".txt-title").val();
            $(".lb_form").fadeOut();                    
    });                                                     
  });
});
```

The value of iTitlesArray is updated only the first time. Does anyone have an idea why?

https://jsfiddle.net/fv3q5fng/1/

Comment: working fine for me. Is it some specific browser worked in FF and chrome

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: the value of the iTitlesArray array is updated only the first time. I added an alert in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in the following line:

```
iTitlesArray[thumbIdInt] = $(".txt-title").val();
```

This will retrieve *all* the `.txt-title` elements on the page and then return the value of the *first* element in the list.

The reason this is the issue is because you are calling `fadeOut()` and not actually removing the previous elements from the DOM. If you remove them after fading this is no longer an issue:

```
$(".lb_form").fadeOut(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fv3q5fng/2/

Answer (score 2):

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv3q5fng/) your code works each time you click on it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

var iTitlesArray = [];  

$(document).on("click", ".add-title", function () { 

var thumbId = $(this).attr("id"), 
    thumbIdInt = parseInt(thumbId);             

var lb_form = $('<div></div>').addClass('lb_form');
var title_input = $('<input type="text">').addClass('txt-title');
var btn = $('<div>Ok</div>').addClass('div-btn');   

lb_form.append(title_input, btn);                   
$('body').append(lb_form);

$( ".div-btn" ).on( "click", function() {
        iTitlesArray[thumbIdInt] = $(".txt-title").val();
        $(".lb_form").fadeOut();                    
});                                                     
});
});
```

Comment: That just goes to jsfiddle.net.

Comment: @TadDonaghe oops.. Thanks